# How to switch off Apache Olingo OData 2.0 caching?

Tags: tomcat, caching, odata, olingo

How to switch off Apache Olingo 2.0 caching?

Web app works in Tomcat 7 and uses MySQL. Its built based on Apache Olingo OData JPA processor.

When I update data record in the database, I can found this data record correctly with this kind of request: "GET /interactive-riga-odata/webservices.svc/Statuss?$filter=(Updated%20gt%20datetime%272014-10-15T12:25:44.054%27) HTTP/1.1"

The problem is, I am getting cached previous version of this data record, even if during the filtering request it was selected based on the new values.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that EclipseLink ORM cache must be disabled or emptied.

Disabling it could be by adding annotations in the model files like this:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class Employee {
```

Or by putting one of these lines in persistance.xml file:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>

<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

If trying to create the solution with data caching, some web service could be used to trigger cache invalidation after some changes in the database (admin interface app pings web services to let them know that MySQL data has changed).